# For $h,k$ harmonic prove that $hk$ is harmonic if and only if $h +ick$ is holomorphic.

Tags: harmonic-functions, potential-theory

This is an exercise from *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* by Ransford. As in the title:

Assume $h,k$ are harmonic and non constant on some domain $D$. Prove that $hk$ is harmonic if and only if $h + ick$ is holomorphic for some real constant $c$. Hint: Consider $f/g$ where $f = h_x -ih_y$, $g=k_x - ik_y$.

What I tried: The functions $f,g$ are holomorphic, and so is $f/g$ (barring zeroes of $g$, but lets not worry about that now). If you look at the real part of $f/g$ then from the other assumptions you get that it's equal to zero. This means that $f/g$ (which is equal to its imaginary part) by holomorphy has to be constant. This leaves us with:

$$
\frac{h_xk_y - h_y k_x}{k_x^2 + k_y^2} = const
$$

Now we would like to somehow extract from this the Riemann Cauchy equations, i.e. arrive at $h_x  = ck_y$, but I'm failing to do so. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have the function $F = \frac{f}{g}$, which is holomorphic in some open neighborhood of the complex plane. Previously, you were able to deduce that
$$F = i\frac{h_xk_y-h_yk_x}{k_x^2+k_y^2}.$$
Notice that, if $F$ is holomorphic, necessarily $F\equiv ic$, where $C\in\mathbb{R}$. This is equivalent to the fact that $f(z)=icg(z)$. Thus,
$$h_x-ih_y = ic(k_x-ik_y).$$
Now, equating real and imaginary parts:
\begin{align}
h_x =& ck_y\\
h_y =& -ck_x.
\end{align}
So, the functions $h$ and $k$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Therefore, $h+ick$ is holomorphic.